# Personal projects involving questionable websites on resume

Tags: resume, projects, employer

I have an open source project that has gained a decent amount of attention and popularity, though it is far from well known. I believe it represents my skills quite nicely.

The thing is, it is associated with a well known, though not necessarily well respected website (hint: it is an anonymous imageboard known for obscene, lewd, childish, and immature content).

Should this be something I leave off my resume, or should I expect employers to look past the association and use it solely to judge my skills?

Comment: Did you design the whole website?

Comment: If the layout is interesting, you could always fill it with *lorem ipsum* and host it somewhere separately.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are the career risks of taking a job related to adult entertainment?](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/11492/what-are-the-career-risks-of-taking-a-job-related-to-adult-entertainment) and of [Displaying Adult Site on a Resume](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/12613/displaying-adult-site-on-a-resume)

Comment: Is that you moot?

Comment: @geekrunner Probably not, I don't think the 4chan code is open-source.

Comment: duplicate of [How should you list a sensitive or questionable project that provided great experience on your resume?](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/3890/how-should-you-list-a-sensitive-or-questionable-project-that-provided-great-expe)

Answer (score 2):

I think that there are clever ways that you can present your experience as a developer on the website without ever explicitly linking the website itself. If your interviewer asks you for more information you can easily have a conversation about the technical merit of your accomplishments, and even discuss what the application did, without ever giving them the URL.